# Dual monitors set to "turn of display in 10 minutes" and only one wakes up after moving the mouse and/or tapping the keyboard

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

The problem happens on multiple machines in our office.  All of them run on Nvidia graphics cards and all use Windows Vista.

Sometimes we can get the dormant monitor to wake up by hitting ctrl+alt+delete, waiting 5 seconds, then hitting escape.  But, sometimes we're forced to reboot.

Anyone else experience this problem and have a fix?

Comment: Have you moved the mouse into the monitor. Here at my setup the second monitor wakes when it has to redraw...

Comment: uhm... yeah.  Tried that.  :-)

Comment: is always the secondary monitor, or the primary does it sometimes, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the exact same hardware, with almost exactly the same set of software, to Windows 7 the problem is gone.  So, I'd say at lease one answer is "Upgrade to Windows 7".

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues like this coming out of hibernation, sleep and even after logging out of the workstation. All of the monitors were hooked up with DVI cables that came with the monitors when they were purchased. After swapping those out for new cables the issue went away.

Comment: Interesting.  Where they Samsung monitors?

Comment: 2 new Samsungs and 2 older Dells. They were just hooked up with the cables on each machine and then after this we changed them out for the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the recent drivers for the graphics?
[**PC hardware: dual monitors, second monitor won't wake up after sleep**](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-7591_102-0.html?threadID=312400),

Comment: All drivers are updated to their most recent available version.